# Как запустить dockerfile вместе с docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Всем привет! Есть такая проблема.. Составил инструкции для docker-compose, где подымаю nginx и всю текущущю директорию запихиваю в контейнер. Но чтобы все хорошо работало, нужно зайти в контейнер и произвести настройку env, так же нужно создать создать миграции (проект на symfony).И собственно сама проблема: как это все автоматизировать? Типа чтобы при команде docker-compose up производились те настройки. Вроде как нужно создать dockerfile? Да? Но как он запуститься одновременно с контейнирами?

Как я делаю. Выполняю команду `docker exec -it {id_php} /bin/bash` и создаю миграции. Как это автоматизировать?

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=tester
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123123
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="yes"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  php-fpm:
    container_name: php
    image: webdevops/php-dev:7.4
    hostname: php-fpm
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    working_dir: "/app"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: webdevops/nginx
    hostname: nginx
    environment:
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /app/public
      WEB_DOCUMENT_INDEX: index.php
      WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - "./:/app"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
```

Вот мой `docker-compose`

Comment: Создаете `Dockerfile` для нужного сервиса, затем в `docker-compose` указываете как именно собирать данный сервис `build: .` в указанном сервисе соберет этот же сервис из `Dockerfile`'a.

Comment: Либо, создайте `.sh` файл с инструкциями и выполните запуск после старта всех сервисов.

Comment: @MoloF Первый вариант мне нравится больше. Получается в сервисе php-fpm нужно создать директиву `build:`  и в ней указать `Dockerfile` и типа все? Могу запускать команду `docker-compose up`

Comment: Опишите подробно список своих действий, я пока не особо понимаю что вы хотите сделать. В `docker-compose` так же есть директива: `command`, в которую можно вписать список собственных команд уже после запуска контейнера, в ней вы так же можете описать необходимые действия ПОСЛЕ запуска контейнера. `Dockerfile` в свою очередь работает ДО запуска, конфигурируя на начальном этапе весь сервис.

Comment: У меня есть проект на symfony, в который я засунул docker-compose. И когда я запускаю проект на новой машине(типа сервер), то я каждый раз захожу в контейнер и запускаю миграции командой `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`. Затем нужно зайти в файл `.env` и изменить в нем данные для доступа к бд. Вот что я имею ввиду.

Comment: Если вы это не прод, а разработка, используйте Makefile где опишите последовательность команд. Примеры, уверен, найдете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но чтобы все хорошо работало, нужно зайти в контейнер и произвести настройку env

Эти действия прописываются в команде `RUN`, не нужно заходить в файловую систему контейнера через запуск с флагом `-it`.

**Пример 1** (Node.js)

Здесь устанавливается `npm` при сборке.

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "app.mjs" ]
```

**Пример 2** (.Net Core)

Здесь еще и указывается переменная среды в `ENV`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim
WORKDIR /App
RUN apt-get update;apt-get install libldap-2.4-2:amd64 -y; ... и еще много чего
COPY . /App
ENV KRB5_KTNAME=/...../win.keytab
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "App.dll"]
```

Пропишите по аналогии инструкции для

> произвести настройку env, так же нужно создать создать миграции

Много инструкций `RUN` использовать не рекомендуется. Создайте одну большую строку из всех необходимых инструкций, проверьте ее в интерактивном режиме запуска контейнера. Если все работает, то ее можно прописывать в `RUN`. Если будут скачиваться пакеты, требующие подтверждения установки (нажатия `y`), добавляйте в конец команды флаг `-y`.